# Quick question regarding vectors.

Tags: vectors

I was working on a problem on my calculator, and I don't have much experience with vectors in general and especially vectors in 4d, but do the vectors

$$
V_1=<1,2,3,4>\\
V_2=<5,6,7,8>\\
V_3=<9,10,11,12>
$$

have a vector that is perpendicular to them? When I do the math, my result is that the only solution is $\vec 0$

Comment: What is your calculation? What do You use? In 4D, there is always at least a vector orthogonal to less than 4 vectors.

Comment: Indeed it can be done. Not so quick answer as your question though. You need the dot product and some matrix stuff...

Comment: I did the determinant of the vector matrix {{e1,e2,e3,e4},{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}. This give a determinant of 0.

Answer (score 1):

$$\langle 9,10,11,12\rangle = 2\langle 5,6,7,8\rangle - \langle 1,2,3,4\rangle$$

So you've just got two linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^4$.  That means that an entire plane is orthogonal to this set of vectors.

You can figure out which vectors by solving this matrix equation $$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8}\pmatrix{w \\ x \\ y \\ z}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$$

Comment: I don't understand. How did you get to there? And how would you solve it. From what I see and know, that can't really be solved from what I have.

Comment: There's a lot that you have to know to understand how I got this formula and how to solve this.  More than I can reasonably put in an answer if I assume that you don't know any basic linear algebra.

Comment: Oh, yeah, if its linear algebra I'll have to wait a semester or two. I am only in calculus 3. I might take it with differential equations next semester, or fall, but it will be a while. I appreciate you candidness. Thanks.